# Users with Read permission can not view the "Pending" alerts inside enterprise wiki pages

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, publishing-site, content-approval

I am working on an Enterprise wiki site collection inside sharepoint on-premises 2013. and i have set the following approval settings:-

[image]

now i edited the home page and i added random text `qqqqqq..` where the status for the page became "Pending".
now when i access the page using contributor user or approve user, they can view the pending change + pending yellow message, as follow:-
[image]

while if i login using a Read user, the user can view the pending change (which sound valid based on the list settings), but the user did not get the yellow pending message, to explain to the user that the page he/she is reading is pending, as follow:-
[image]

so can anyone advice if i can allow the Reader users to view the pending yellow message similar to contributors and above?

Comment: Is the Super User and Super Reader property set on the Web Application?

Comment: @TrevorSeward can you advice more on this please?

Answer (score 0):

The yellow bar will not show up unless you have "Approver" permissions, typically you don't want "readers" to be able to see unapproved changes until they have been approved by someone with the appropriate permissions.  This controls what what changes are shown to the average end user, and ensures that they don't see a change that they are not supposed to see.

Comment: your reply is not accurate, the yellow bar will show for contributor + in our case reader can see pending pages, since we are allowing any user with read permission to view draft items (as per the screen shot i provide).. so can you re-read my question and the screens provided?